# Get 2 fabric canvas into one image

Tags: canvas, todataurl

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas',{backgroundColor: 'rgb(105,105,105)'});
var textCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('textCanvas');

function CanvasData()
{   
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    var elem = document.getElementById("canvasData");
    // elem.value = dataUrl;
    // window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
    var canvasone = canvas;
    var ctx1 = canvasone.getContext("2d");
    var canvastwo = textCanvas;
    var ctx2 = canvastwo.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.drawImage(ctx2, 0, 0);
    var dataUrl = canvasone.toDataURL();
    elem.value = dataUrl;
}
```

How do I get 2 fabric canvas and put `toDataURL()` and output a combine image with those 2 canvas? I tried to use draw, but I cant get it.

Answer (score 1):

*The following code is untested and may need some tweaking...*

Given that you have 2 canvases controlled by FabricJS:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas');
var textCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('textCanvas');
```

Get a reference to those original canvases like this:

```
var myImageCanvas=document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var myTextCanvas=document.getElementById('textCanvas');
```

Create a new third canvas to hold the combined canvases. (Or if you don't care about overwriting the imageCanvas, you could use the imageCanvas itself).

```
var output=document.createElement('canvas');
var octx=output.getContext('2d');
```

Draw imageCanvas & textCanvas onto the new canvas.

Notice that you **use the canvas element as the image source**. The code in your question tries to use a context as an image source -- that won't work.

```
octx.drawImage(myImageCanvas,0,0);
octx.drawImage(myTextCanvas,0,0);
```

Finally, create an image from the new canvas using .toDataURL

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
img.src=output.toDataURL();
```